# Delete All Cookies with PHP is only deleting a single cookie

Tags: php, cookies, isset

I've tried to make script to delete all cookies from a domain however it's not quite working.

The `// Delete Cookies #3` part deletes cookies correctly however it only deletes a single cookie at a time... I need it to delete all cookies before redirecting.

What have I done wrong in the code that's only allowing it to delete a single cookie?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button "Delete Cookies" and press yes if you want to delete all of your browser cookies for this website.</p>

<button onclick="DeleteCookies()">Delete Cookies</button>

<script>
function DeleteCookies() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all of your browser cookies for this website?")) {
      window.location.replace("https://website.com/RemoveCookies.php?delete=1");
  } else {
      window.location.replace("https://website.com/");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['delete'])) {
        
        // Delete Cookies #1 - Doesn't delete ALL cookies
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
            $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
            foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
                $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
                $name = trim($parts[0]);
                setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
                setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
            }
        }
    
        // Delete Cookies #2 - Doesn't delete ALL cookies
        $past = time() - 3600;
        foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ) {
            setcookie( $key, $value, $past, '/' );
        }
        
        // Delete Cookies #3 (Works at deleting all cookies but has to be run multiple times?)
        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $domain = explode(':', $host)[0];
    
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $uri = rtrim(explode('?', $uri)[0], '/');
    
        if ($uri && !filter_var('file://' . $uri, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            throw new Exception('invalid uri: ' . $uri);
        }
    
        $parts = explode('/', $uri);
    
        $cookiePath = '';
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            $cookiePath = '/'.ltrim($cookiePath.'/'.$part, '//');
    
            setcookie($name, '', 1, $cookiePath);
    
            $_domain = $domain;
            do {
                setcookie($name, '', 1, $cookiePath, $_domain);
            } while (strpos($_domain, '.') !== false && $_domain = substr($_domain, 1 + strpos($_domain, '.')));
        }
        
        Header("Location: https://website.com/");
        
    }
?>
```

If I try any of the cookie delete scripts individually they dont delete cookies... but if I try all 3 together it eventually works by stepping through over and over until they're all gone.

However if I run a loop it errors out on the server for some reason.

Comment: `// Delete Cookies #1` Should work well. Maybe you have time misconfiguration on the server?

Comment: And could you provide us the dump of `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']`?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get #1, #2 or #3 to work however doing the following did work:

```
foreach ($_COOKIE AS $key => $value) {
     setcookie($key, $value, time()-1000, "/", ".domain.com");
     setcookie($key, $value, time()-1000, "/", "domain.com");
     setcookie($key, $value, time()-1000, "/", "www.domain.com");
     setcookie($key, $value, time()-1000, "/");
     setcookie($key, $value, time()-1000);
}
```

The first two **setcookie** lines were the two that made the biggest difference for this particular scenario.